# Seeing a CD Key without steam open

Tags: steam

Is there a way to find the key to a steam game without having steam open because i need my key to get my account info because someone stole my account...

Comment: You need to give a game key to get your steam account back?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to get the Steam key for a game you've redeemed on Steam without using Steam.

In fact, I'm not aware of a way to do this if you have Steam running - once the key is redeemed, Steam doesn't typically give you any way to view it.

The exception is games that have keys beyond the Steam system.  These games you can view the "CD Key" or similar in the Steam library view for the game.  However, there is no way to get this information without being logged into Steam.

I would suggest contacting [Steam customer support](https://support.steampowered.com/) in your case.